Reference Request: Pushforward of $\pi_1$ along a covering map and the Galois group
Let $f \colon (Y,y_0) \to (X,x_0)$ be a finite-to-one pointed covering map. The pushforward gives an inclusion $f_* \colon \pi_1(Y,y_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$. If we take the universal cover $\widetilde{X}$ of $X$ and mod out by the action of the image $f_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))$, we get a cover of $X$ that is naturally isomorphic to $Y$. If $f$ is an abelian cover (i.e., normal, such that the group of deck transformations is abelian), then we can replace $\pi_1(-)$ by $H_1(-,\mathbb{Z})$ and this all goes through.
This is in analogy to the situation in Galois theory: Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension. The absolute Galois group $G_L$ is a subgroup of $G_K$, since $\overline{L} = \overline{K}$, and any automorphism that fixes $L$ will also fix $K$. If the extension is normal, we have $G_K/G_L \cong \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$. (In this analogy, the inclusion $G_L \to G_K$ is the pushforward $f_* \colon \pi_1(Y,y_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$.)
The questions:

What happens when we relax the condition that $f$ is finite-to-one? I know that, in the field extension case, we get the extra information that $G_L$ is a closed subgroup of $G_K$ in the profinite topology; this is what allows $G_K/G_L$ to inherit the topology of $G_K$. Should I think that there is some notion of a profinite covering map, and that the theory extends just like it does in the case of fields with algebraic extensions? Specifically, can I say that $f_* \colon \pi_1(Y,y_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$ is injective, its image is a closed, normal subgroup, and that the quotient $\pi_1(X,x_0)/f_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))$ is isomorphic to the group of deck transformations $\operatorname{Aut}(Y/X)$ as topological groups?

Is there a good reference I can give here? The infinite case is important for my application, specifically the profinite case. Should I just cite somewhere in Grothendieck?



I think you are asking about what some topologists call the "Galois correspondence". Namely, there is a natural bijection between subgroups of $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ and path-connected pointed covers of $X$ (up to pointed isomorphism).  For this to go through $X$ needs to be a bit nice (say a path-connected CW complex).  However, we don't need to (and in fact can't) assume that the subgroups are normal, or that the covers are finite. This is spelled out in Chapter 1 of Hatcher - see Theorem 1.38.

There is no profinite topology in the classical topological setting. The reason it appears in the étale setting is that any separable algebraic extension $\operatorname{Spec} L \to \operatorname{Spec} K$ is a limit of finite extensions (i.e. $K \to L$ is a colimit of finite extensions). A field does not have a 'true' universal cover, only something that looks like a universal cover through this profinite lens (the spectrum of a separable algebraic closure).
